# Hortonworks Sandbox: How to Install HBase Thrift + REST servers

Tags: rest, hbase, thrift, hortonworks-data-platform

Looking at [the Hortonworks Documentation](http://dev.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-Trunk/bk_ambari_reference/content/reference_chap2_4_2x.html), it appears that
the following servers are not installed by default.

- HBase REST Server (optional)
- HBase REST Server Web UI (optional)
- HBase Thrift Server (optional)
- HBase Thrift Server Web UI (optional)

What is the standard way to install them in Hortonworks?

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the web:

> If you have a server where the HBase Master or Region Server is
>   installed then you can start it [**HBase REST Server**]. If it is on the Ambari server then
>   the default port 8080 will conflict with the Ambari port and you will
>   have to specify the port which it should listen on.

*Source*: h.ttp://de.hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/not-able-to-use-hbase-thru-hue/

I also tried to find a solution for the port-issue, and here is what i found:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.1/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap5-3-10.html

That means you have to change the default port of the HBase REST Server.

Now to the **Thrift Server**: I can only find how to start it, so I think it is installed with the HBase Master or Region Server installation. Here is also mentioned how to start the HBase REST Server:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-latest/bk_installing_manually_book/content/ch06s05.html

Maybe the port-issue has been solved with the command `--infoport 8085`. Please let me know if this helped.

PS: Sorry for the first link but I can only post two links.